# I cannot edit my dns zone in godaddy whm

Tags: dns, shared-hosting, whm

I have bought a vps plan on godaddy and I want to configure my domain settings.
I followed the instructions mentioned here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4xNNyb5y7o
It is not my first time to do though, but after creating new account I get this:
[This is a picture of the error I get when creating a new account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7OGt.png)

and when I try to edit my dns zone I get this:
[the error I get when editing the dns zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Con0g.png)

```
; cPanel first:11.72.0.4 (update_time):1530021773 11.72.0.4: Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:s132-148-245-18.secureserver.net latest:11.72.0.4
; Zone file for el7p.com
$TTL 14400
@      86400    IN      SOA     ns1.secureserver.net. info.. ( near 'info..': empty label
        2018062600  ; serial, todays date+todays
        3600        ; refresh, seconds
        7200        ; retry, seconds
        1209600     ; expire, seconds
        86400 )     ; minimum, seconds

el7p.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.secureserver.net.
el7p.com. 86400 IN NS ns2.secureserver.net.


el7p.com. IN A 132.148.245.18

el7p.com. IN MX 0 el7p.com.

mail IN CNAME el7p.com.
www IN CNAME el7p.com.
ftp IN A 132.148.245.18
el7p.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:10.193.90.225 ~all"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your Zone file.

The line `@ 86400 IN SOA ns1.secureserver.net. info.. ( near 'info..': empty label` contains the word 'info... ' and that's what's causing the problem for you.

It should read as; `@ 86400 IN SOA ns1.secureserver.net. hostmaster.el7p.com. (` Note the '(' should be there as its closed a few lines below and groups all the `TTL` settings together.

The `hostmaster` section should contain a valid email contact (without the `@`) for the domain.